# Can I update staticLayer with the laserData?

Tags: ros, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to update static layer with the data from lidar.Is that OK?

My thought is that call this function StaticLayer::incomingMap(new_map),the parameter "new_map"is from the lidar?

Why it can be done? or why not? thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271025/can-i-update-staticlayer-with-the-laserdata?/) by [pengjiawei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31790/pengjiawei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 138 on 2017-09-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

yes , it can be done and I did it successfully

---

Originally posted by [pengjiawei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31790/pengjiawei/) with karma: 138 on 2018-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-09**:
This answer would be greatly improved if you included *how* to do it.